# SSL Form Post in ASP.NET MVC 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl

I'd like to use SSL for the post action on the login page of my MVC 1.0 app.  I've seen some articles related to the [RequireSSL] attribute in ASP.NET MVC Futures.  However, since this works using a redirect, I assume it's not an option (can't redirect a POST, correct?).

Ultimately, my goal is to get the Html.BeginForm method to render "https://..." as the form's action so that I can secure the information being posted (login info).

How have others handled this?

Comment: So you want to post from a non-SSL page to a SSL one, yea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could secure the form GET as well. If the form is retrieved with HTTPS, `Html.BeginForm` will automatically add `https` when rendering the form.

Comment: Thanks.  I just arrived at that same conclusion.  Don't know why I didn't think of that earlier.